# How to find out motherboard storage capacity.?

Tags: motherboard

will my motherboard will support 4 TB hard disk..?
Below is my configuration of my pc
Moherboard- H81M-S
RAM- 4GB
Processor- i3 quad core 3.50Ghz.

Comment: Manual says...?

Comment: The mainboard doesn't typically control the possible capacity of the drives to be attached to it. Addressing is a function of the format of the drive and (possibly) the drivers the OS uses. Are you having a problem connecting a specific-size drive to your system, or are you asking before you purchase a drive?

Comment: Your user manual with specs....http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-h81m-s_e.pdf

Comment: no i have already purchased it but having problem while partitioning. Only 2 TB of storage get partitioned rest it shows unallocated in boot menu. So i heard from someone that check online or manual that whether your motherboard supports 4TB hard disk or not. I checked but did'nt find.

Answer (score 1):

**Your motherboard supports UEFI** which is needed to boot from a disk that is greater than 2TB and the device must be initialized by using GUID partition table (GPT). On the other hand UEFI is not needed to have a non-bootable drive, only GPT.

However if your disk is MBR, it will be recognised as a 2TB drive. You need to convert it to GTP.

**To do that:**

- Run **diskmgmt** (Disk Management)
- You will see an unrecognised disk in *usually* two separtate unallocated partitions. You have to make it a single allocated partition that contains all the space the drive can offer. Right click on the disk and select "**Convert to GTP Disk**".
- After the conversion is done, you will see the partitions have merged into one.
- Now you have to make the disk active. Right click, select "**New Single Volume**", then the disk wizard will help you thru.

Comment: thank you so much. But i have bought a new hard disk which in result i have to install OS first on that hard drive. So is there any other way that i can convert it to gpt from boot menu & after gpt will i able to partition in 2 size 760gb & 3TB.?

Comment: You can convert the disk to GPT during Windows setup (if that what you want to install). When the "Install Now" screen pops up, select "Repair my computer" / Advanced / Command Prompt. Type the following, "---" means ENTER.
diskpart  ---
list disk   //now you have to select the disk you want to convert to GPT// ---
select disk "disk number, for example 0" ---
clean ---
convert GPT ---

And thats all, reboot your computer and you can now install the OS the regular way. You can partition the disk any way you want during the installation or when the installation is complete. Good Luck!